# EF Core Explicit loading multiple nested tables

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I work with EF Core 3.1 and I want load related data of child tables via explicit loading.

I have 4 tables - A, Aa, Ab, A_Ab (1 principal and 2 related tables - 1:N and M:N (scheme on picture))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyKqi.png)

If I wanted to use Eager Loading code syntax is here:

```
var result = context.A
    .Include(x => x.Aa)
    .Include(x => x.A_Ab)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Ab)
    .ToList();
```

But I want load only A and then with Explicit Loading Aa, Ab - any idea how to do that?